# How to exclude task in portfolioitem/features in from the Rally.ui.grid.TreeGrid

Tags: rally, code-rally

How can we exclude task from the portfoliitem/feature tree node from the rally tree grid?

for eg.

```
userstory 1 - subuserstory1 - - subsubuserstory1 - testcase,task
```

**desired output**

```
userstory 1 - subuserstory1 - - subsubuserstory1 - testcase
```

Comment: Have you written any code you can share?  The built-in tree grid will always show all levels of available hierarchy, but you can trim some of it out by writing a custom app.